# H2 Server consume 1G memory to load a 250m file based database?

Tags: database, memory, load, h2

I got several report from application users of out of memory exception when connecting to a H2 server. When trying to reproduce, I used jconsole to connect to the H2 server and check what's going on.

I found when I connect to the H2 server and load a database the first time, H2 server start consuming a lot of memory. Before loading any database, the H2 server only consume 3M memory. After using Squirrel SQL client connecting to the H2 and load the 250M file database, H2 server consume about 1G memory. What could be the reason this happen?

H2 server start command: 
java -Xmx2g -Xms16m -XX:PermSize=16m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -cp "h2-1.3.173.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9097 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir C:\temp\h2db

My connection string: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9097/db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

---

Additional information:
We have quite some tables(1200+) in the database, and 800+ views which union or join on these tables. Will this be the cause of this problem? Could there be any solutions that reduce the memory consumption when loading such database?

Comment: Well, you're allowing it to consume up to 2G of heap (`-Xmx2g`) so the JVM won't be that motivated to gc permanently.  What happens if you reduce the -Xmx setting, say to `-Xmx128m`?  Also, are you sure the db you're creating is an on disk db and not a memory db?

Comment: Even when using -Xmx512M, the server won't be able to load the 250M database and will report out of memory. 
When using 2G heap, after the database is loaded and I force it to do GC, there are still around 800M heap memory used.
The database is stored on disk for sure because I can see that db1.h2.db file which has the size 250M. I think my connection string specify it as a file based database, not a in-memory db. Am I correct?

Comment: No, your connection specifies it as a server connection, but servers can offer access to both persistent and in memory databases.  When running in disk-only mode h2 should never need 2GB to run a db.

Comment: I think for h2 connection string, it will be memory database only when you specify "mem:". In my case, I didn't specify this option, so the db1 should be a file db. To verify this, I use a new connection string: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9097/file:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1, which declare the "file:" option for db1 to make sure it's file db. And this issue still happen.

Comment: True.  You might want to generate a heapdump once the db is loaded, and have a look at it with either JVisualVM or Eclipse MAT, to see where all the memory went.  It's been a while since I last did "big" and persistent things with h2, but what you're describing is not its normal behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the heap dump, it's found that most of those memory are occupied by view metadata. For our case, there are 2500+ views, and their metadata occupied 550M heap size. The detail discussion about this can be found here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/4IWPu70yY5U

Thomas acknowledge that the current h2 view metadata should be improved to reduce the memory usage.